# What is “post patent expiration”?

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

> GMCR paid high prices to avoid having to compete with licensees post patent expiration.

Is *post* a verb here, or is it a part of *post patent expiration*? What does it mean?

Comment: Try reading it with a substitution and a helpful hyphen:  "GMCR paid high prices to avoid having to compete with licensees **after** patent-expiration."

Answer (score 4):

*Post* is here used as a preposition meaning after.  It is a legal borrowing from Latin.

The OED gives an unusual note under sense 9 for the preposition, which is the one used with English words or phrases:

> Usu. found in contexts where *after* would be equally appropriate and more agreeable. —Ed.

That’s uncommonly condemning of them. Then again, when you look at the citations they provide, you begin to see why they said that:

> - **1965** *Listener* 16 Sept. 432/3 ― *Der Ferne Klang* is post-Wagnerian, and post just about everything else that was happening at the turn of the century.
> - **1973** *Nature* 26 Jan. 273/1 ― Medium was replaced two days post plating and the number of foci determined on the third day.
> - **1974** *Daily Tel.* 7 Jan. 13/3 ― Now, post the increase [in the price of oil],··future gold price prospects far outweigh individual share fundamentals.
> - **1979** *Daily Tel.* 19 July 21/4 ― Post the Geneva meeting of Opec the OECD reckons that its 24 member countries··can expect average economic growth of only two p.c. over the next 12 months.

It’s also interesting that all their citations are from periodicals.  The first is reasonable because of its use as a prefix for an open compound in parallel with the *post-* prefix, the second a bit more dubious, and the last two from the *Daily Telegraph* just plain silly.

Comment: So what does this sentence mean?

Comment: @EricKao It means that GMCR paid high prices to avoid having to compete with licensees after patent expiration.

Comment: In other words, it means "after the patents have expired".